# magnific popup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am using Magnific Popup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-viewer').magnificPopup({
      type: 'ajax'
  });
});
```

This is the html:

```
<a href="/site-media/{{ photo.image }}" class="image-viewer"><img class="fest-content-event-content-photo" width = "100%" src="/site-media/{{ photo.thumbnail2 }}" /></a>
```

But, it isn't working and the console shows error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function (index):30
(anonymous function) (index):30
fire jquery.js:3048
self.fireWith jquery.js:3160
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:433
completed
```

What is wrong? I have not loaded tje jquery.js file twice.

Comment: Where is your relevant `code`? We can find errors.. but the first line looks a bit... errorish.

Comment: It looks like you have a conflict, try the answer above and tell us if  you're still getting same error

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you've included the jQuery library properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Secondly, maybe there is a conflict between jQuery with other libraries, you can try to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     $('.image-viewer').magnificPopup({
          type: 'ajax'
     });
});
```

Comment: the error is firing by Jquery `fire jquery.js:3048` so for sure he's including it properly

Comment: i have included the libary.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have conflict.. try adding a `$` in the `document.ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.image-viewer').magnificPopup({
      type: 'ajax'
  });
});
```

Or replace the `$` with `jQuery`  this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('.image-viewer').magnificPopup({
          type: 'ajax'
      });
}
```

Comment: i think you didn't read my question. I have included it inside the ready function.

Comment: i have other code as well in the rady function(). So, do i have to change it everywhere or should I just define another ready function?

Comment: Just change the `document.ready function` with one of theses and tell me if you're still getting any arrors pls. If it is not working pls provide your entire code.

Comment: ok i got it solved. I had placed the js file for magnific popup befor the jQuery.js. Now its solved.

Comment: Ok cool. Next time provide more code as it is easier to find bug.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you put the JQuery and Magnific js links before the code to be executed.

Something like below:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#some-btn').magnificPopup({
        items: [
          {
            src: './9414795.jpg'
          }
        ],
        gallery: {
          enabled: true
        },
        type: 'image'
      });
    });
  </script>
```